# Disable a service from starting at all runlevels?

Tags: debian, startup, debian-lenny, daemon, rc.d

I have a service `foo` which currently starts at runlevel *3* and above. How can I stop it from doing so, without using `update-rc.d foo stop 3 .`, which (if I understand it correctly) would turn off the service at each runlevel change.

(ie., if I was at runlevel *1* and enabled `foo`, then when I changed to runlevel *3* it would be disabled, no?)

Running Debian GNU/Linux Lenny.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The "stop" term does not prevent the daemon from starting but rather shuts it down while entering the specified runlevel.

If you just want to remove a service/daemon from a single runlevel, `update-rc.d` as pointed out bei *freiheit* or **simply remove the symlink** from `/etc/rcX.d/`, where X is your runlevel. If you don't want the service to start automatically, `update-rc.d -f foo remove` will do the trick.

Comment: Any ideas how to do it on Debian 8? `sudo update-rc.d -f sunrpc remove` does not work; its still present after a reboot.

Comment: Debian 9 This wasn't working for me, and then I realized, oh derp, need sudo. update-rc.d gives no feedback if you forget to sudo. I confirmed the links were gone with `ls /etc/rc*.d`

Comment: The command failed on Ubuntu `16.04`

Comment: Make sure you pass the correct service name, update-rc.d does not give you any feedback if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What if you want to re-enable it later? Below @"Not Now"'s answer is better, as you can disable and re-enable after. `update-rc.d apache2 disable`

Comment: About `remove`, the [docs](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/init-system-helpers/update-rc.d.8.en.html) says, "The script must have been deleted already", and, "update-rc.d is usually called from a package's post-removal script when that script is given the purge argument." As for removing symlinks by hand, at least if you want to disable a service on all run levels it's best to use `update-rc.d SERVICE disable`, or else the symlinks will be restored on subsequent package upgrade.

Answer (score 60):

[Configure Linux Startup Applications with sysv-rc-conf](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2007/08/29/configure-linux-startup-applications-with-sysv-rc-conf/):

```
apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

As others have pointed out, here is also [update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) for the cmd line.

For example, run

```
update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

to disable apache2 from all run levels.

Comment: note that this won't stop the running service, to achieve that you neet to add this: `service foo stop` or reboot the server

Answer (score 16):

Short:

**There is no reliable way to do this quickly.**

Long:

Current Debian (Debian unstable as of 2012-06-01) has currently no reliable short way to consistently disable a service/daemon. – Because an upgrade of a daemon package unconditionally runs “/etc/init.d/package restart”, having it disabled for this runlevel or not.

To make sure a daemon doesn’t start, you could:

- uninstall it
- make a local divert of the /etc/init.d/xyz script (this way, no tools will find it)
- use/abuse a config file of the corresponding package to provoke an early exit of that script (e.g. put an “exit” early in /etc/default/xyz in case it is sourced from the init script)
- look in that init-script for predefined “official” ways to not start that daemon

There is/was(?) some init-policy-something step for init scripts in Debian, which was supposed to fill this missing functionality. – I tried to use it, found it complicated, found a bug, and never touched it again.

**Update:**

Switch to “systemd”, an alternative to “initd”. A debian package exists, and you can disable a service with something like this:

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
ln -s /dev/null xyz.service
```

Comment: +1 This is such a helpful answer - and if I hadn't happened upon it I would have been stung later on - thanks!

Comment: Can you just ````unlink xyz.service```` as well?

Comment: @NextLocal, I forgot why I wrote that, but I believe if a service has System V init scripts, `systemd` will use them. – So the link tells it not to look for them.

Comment: Note that editing the `/etc/default/xyz` file to add an `exit` will not prevent the packager to overwrite the file with the correct version on the next upgrade. (The package saves configuration files, and in most cases init scripts are not viewed as such.) So in most cases that would not help.

Comment: Devuan comes to the rescue: instead of systemd it embraces the classic SysV rc.d/init.d system (or openrc as well if someone opts for that).

Answer (score 6):

Run this command

apt-get install rcconf

Once installed, run rcconf in SSH and you will receive a dialog box displaying all services set to run on boot. Select the ones by pressing Space to disable/enable the particular and you're done, simpley click on Ok and that service wont bother to start again on next boot. Being using this for years. Very handy tool for Debian/Ubuntu users like me.

Comment: Easy as 1,2,3! Thanks for this little command line tool.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused what you're trying to accomplish.

What run levels do you want foo running in?

If you always want it running, use `update-rc.d foo defaults`; that will stop it in 0, 1 and 6, while leaving it running in 2, 3, 4 and 5.  (1 shouldn't run anything but a shell, 0 and 6 are halt and reboot)

If you want to specify exactly what run levels to run in:

```
update-rc.d foo stop 0 1 6 3 . start 2 4 5 .
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this would do the job: insserv -r foo

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo update-rc.d SERVICE disable
```

If you want to specify run levels.

```
sudo update-rc.d SERVICE disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
```

Remember to change *service* to the name of the program.

```
sudo service SERVICE restart
```

Comment: Best answer for systems not using systemd

Answer (score 1):

Start using insserv from Debian7

Output all services and it runlevel information

```
insserv --showall
```

Remove the listed scripts from all runlevels

```
insserv --remove [specify_script]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you backup the startup script somewhere else and remove it in the /etc/init.d/ ? If the update-rc.d doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

On a red hat based system you could use

```
chkconfig httpd off
chkconfig httpd --del
```

to remove the server from runlevels

on debian based system all services are supposed to be started by the files found in the /etc/rc?.d/ directories 
these files then have a symbolic link to the corresponding files in the /etc/init.d/ directory. If you wish for a service not to start by default then you can rename/remove it from the /etc/rc?.d directory and your change will be preserved on package upgrade as long as one of the start links still appear in one of the other (3,4 and 5) directories.
Or you can use the update-rc.d command to change the link(s) and if you want to start the service after then you can use /etc/init.d/service_name start if you leave the start off the end it will give you the options that can be used like stop, restart, reload ...

I think you can use sysv-rc-conf to disable it though.

Comment: The question is tagged Debian, not Fedora or Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's Bootup Manager is kind of sysv-rc-conf *light*, a more friendly, GUI version, and many folks reading this thread will appreciate that.

http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html